# PHP Escaping String Error

Tags: php, mysql

Little problem giving me lots of errors: I can't get the escapes right…

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR in /home/indyprogramming/public_html/Board.php on line 34

```
include "layout.top.php";   
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result[0] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `indy_thread` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "' LIMIT 1");
$row[0] = mysql_fetch_array($result[0]);    
print "<div align=\"left\">\n";     $que = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `indy_forums` WHERE `hash` = '" . $row[0]['connector'] . "'");    $wor = mysql_fetch_array($que); print "<div><a href=\"index.php\">Index</a> -> <a href=\"Forum.php?id=".$wor['id']."\">".$wor['name']."</a> -> " . $row[0]['name'] . "</div>\n <br />\n";       print "<div class=\"c_1\">\n";
print "\n";
print $row[0]['name'] . "\t <br />\n";
print "\n";
print "</div>\n";
print "<div style=\"height:5px;\">&nbsp;</div>\n";
$result[1] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `indy_posts` WHERE `connector`='" . $row[0]['hash'] . "' ORDER BY `id` ASC");
$i = 0;
while( $row[1] = mysql_fetch_array( $result[1] ) )
{

    print "<div ";
    if( $i != ( mysql_num_rows( $result[1] ) - 1 ) )        {
        print "style=\"border-bottom:0px;\" ";
    }
    print "class=\"t_1\">\n";

    if( ($_COOKIE['id']) AND ($user['class'] != "Member") )
    {


    print "<div style=\"position:relative;top:0px;left:25px;\"><a href=\"#\" onClick=\"loadDiv('post_" . ($i+1) . "', '/edit.message.php?id=".$row[1]['id']."')\">Edit this Message</a> || <a href=\"/d.msg.php?id=".$row[1]['id']."\">Delete this Message</a></div>\n";


    }

    print "<div style=\"position:relative;top:10px;left:25px;\"><b>".replace(getUserData($row[1]['poster'],'name'))."</b></div>\n";     
    print "<div style=\"position:relative;top:10px;left:25px;\">" . $row[1]['date'] . "</div>\n";
    print "<div id=\"post_".$i+1.\" style=\"position:relative;top:50px;left:25px;max-width:750px;height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;border-right:1px solid #111;\">";

    $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/fposts/" . $row[1]['message'] . ".txt";
    $file = fopen( $filename, "r+" );
    $display = fread( $file, filesize( $filename ) );
    fclose( $file );
    print replace( $display );

    print "</div>\n";



    print "</div>\n"; 
    $i = $i + 1;

}

if($user_logged)
{
    print "<br /><br />\n";
    print "<div align=\"center\">\n";
    print "<div><h2><b>Quick Reply @".$user['name']."</b></h2></div>\n";
    print "<form action=\"/post.board.php?id=".$row[0]['id']."\" method=\"post\">\n";
    include "msg.box.php";
    print "<br />\n <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Go!\" />\n";
    print "</form>\n";
    print "</div>\n";
}
print "</div>\n";
include "layout.bottom.php";
```

Comment: And the great question is, where is line 34?

Comment: use a few single quotes then you wouldn't have to do so much quote escaping. example `print 'style="border-bottom:0px;" ';` easier to read and debug

Comment: You should really consider using a template engine. What you currently have would take ages to fix, change or maintain. Please consider using Twig or other similar template engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line had the quotes wrong. This should work-

```
print "<div id=\"post_". $i+1 ."\" style=\"position:relative;top:50px;left:25px;max-width:750px;height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;border-right:1px solid #111;\">";
//                           ^Added a extra " to complete the id quotes.
```

Comment: their needs to be in order to end the id="" tag

Comment: now its Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/indyprogramming/public_html/Board.php on line 26, i usually don't have problems with this its making me very angry   print "<div id=\"post_".$i+1."\" style=\"position:relative;top:50px;left:25px;max-width:750px;height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;border-right:1px solid #111;\">";

Comment: @user3272334 line 26 seems to be fine, but in line 34(the line that I have mentioned in the answer), give a space between 1 and dot(,) like this - ....$i+1 ."\... See my edit

Comment: well it pointed me to the right answer so yes thank you very much